How do I print out what is sent via 'send()' in a c script
I am trying to understand what a certain c script sends via LAN. It uses this function:
send(sock_client, buffer, n * 16, MSG_NOSIGNAL) 

I understand (maybe incorrectly) that this function sends n*16 bytes, starting at buffer.
And my very basic question is how to check what is exactly sent there. For this purpose I want to write the same numbers that are sent to a file. It looks like fwrite shoule to the job, but so far I did not understand how to use it.
This produces a bunch of jibberish:
fwrite(buffer, 1, n * 16, fptr);

Thank you!
Marco

What you interpret as a bunch of jibberish may well be meaningful information to the communicating parties.

Are you sure that you send printable data? What is the data you send? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

send and fwrite handle binary raw data. They do not convert that data into human readable text as fprintf would do. If you want to log the data in some readable format (as hex digits or similar) then you must do it on your own using fprintf.

Since you can edit the program, you should probably just print the data in a human-readable format like hexadecimal. One option would be to write the data to a file, then xxd or hexdump the resulting file (or use a hex editor to view it).

On POSIX type systems, you can use write to write to the socket, e.g. write(sock_client, buffer, n * 16);. fwrite uses standard I/O streams. It is possible to use standard I/O streams on sockets but because sockets are non-seekable, you would need to open a separate stream for each direction: fpin = fdopen(dup(socket_client), "r"); fpout = fdopen(socket_client, "w");. You also need to be aware of standard I/O buffering, especially for connectionless protocols such as UDP.

Why not use a packet capture application like Wireshark instead of changing your code?

Use a "dump" function :-)
void fdump(FILE *f, const char *pre, const unsigned char *data, size_t n, const char *post) {
    if (!n) return;
    if (!f) f = stdout;
    if (pre) fprintf(f, "%s", pre);
    fprintf("%02x", *data++);                    // 1st byte raw
    while (--n) fprintf(f, " %02x", *data++);    // other bytes with a space
    if (post) fprintf(f, "%s", post);
}

--
send(sock_client, buffer, n * 16, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
fdump(fptr, "Data dump: [", buffer, n * 16, "]\n");


Here is what did the trick:
// Open the file
FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
// Write array to file:
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     fprintf(file, "buffer[%d] = %u\n", i, buffer[i]);
    }
// Close the file
fclose(file);

